# Terminal bash commands stopped working

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, script

I was trying to install some stuff for scala development on my MAC, and probably I managed broke the shell/terminal while I was mindlessly running some scripts that I don't know.

Now when I start the terminal it always starts with this line;

```
$ /sbin:sbin:/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier
```

And now when I try, I see some bash commands does not work, for instance grep, syslog..etc I get an error saying;

```
-bash syslog: "no such file or directory"
```

Any idea what is wrong and how can I fix this

Comment: What files did you edit did you edit when you did the install - probably your shell initialization files e.g. .bashrc, .bash_profile and others

Comment: FYI, to disable customizations so you can start a shell to edit a shell startup script, you can use Terminal's **Shell > New Command** item to run `bash --noprofile`, which will start Bash without running the login script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to edit the .profile or .bash_rc file on the terminal

```
 /usr/bin/vi ~/.profile
```

and see if one of the software has put stuff in there that should not be there (especially if one has put up a messed PATH command there).  (Alternately but less likely affected are  `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/vi /etc/profile` or `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/vi /etc/bashrc`).

If you don't know how to use the VI editor, you can also use `/usr/bin/nano` instead of `/usr/bin/vi`

For a start, until you find where this happens, editing the .profile (see above) you can put the following command as the last command to the end of your ~/.profile file.

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

This should at least give you back access to your normal commands.

Comment: tnx for the quick fix I will try that, but I didnt understand what should I do with the files you mentioned, and no idea how should I edit them

Comment: For a first diag (most likely culprit), show/add the current content of your ~/.profile file in your question text

Comment: tnx I will do it in evening

Comment: I just checked, there is no .profile file under ~/. how should I put it back? I dont use time machine

Comment: ahh I checked bashprofile file. and there was an extra space in one of the paths! problem solved! but .profile is still missing..hope thats not a problem